# Halloween Candy Power Ranking in R: which of combination of properties lead to an increase in the victory rate

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I dont know if you are familiar with the Candy-Power-Ranking Data.
But the data looks like this:

```
Chocolade   Caramel  Fruit  Win%
1            1        0      0,8
0            1        0      0,54
0            0        0      0,23
1            1        1      0,49
```

Now I want to check which combination of properties lead to an higher Win%.

What I already did is a Multiple linear regression

```
lmodel = lm(candy_data$Win% ~ candy_data$chocolade + candy_data$caramel + candy_data$fruit)
summary(lmodel)
```

That gives me the info which propertie leads to an higher Win%. But I want to check which combinaton is the best. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you're looking for combinations, try `lm(Win% ~ chocolade * caramel * fruit, data = candy_data)`. See the meaning of the formulas in [11.1  Defining statistical models; formulae](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf),  or the same section in file R-intro.pdf that comes with all distributions of R.

Comment: But how do I get the best combination?

Comment: That is a question about statistics and therefore more suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but what do the regression coefficients tell you? And the biggest positive coef is ...